# Understanding convertView

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to understand how convertView works. I did read most of the documents that I came across and also questions on StackOverflow. I thought I've understood how it works, but when it comes to implementation, I couldn't get it right.

My code as of now:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(Const.DEBUGGING){
        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Position = "+position);
    }

    if (convertView == null) {

        if(Const.DEBUGGING){
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "convertView is NULL");
        }

        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.item_mtf_results, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewResults = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textview_item_mtf_results);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        if(Const.DEBUGGING){
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "convertView is NOT Null");
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtViewResults.setText(dummyText[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

My Logcat for above code :

```
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 0
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 1
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 2
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 3
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 4
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 5
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 6
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 7
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): Position = 8
03-30 10:27:29.433: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): Position = 0
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): Position = 1
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): Position = 2
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): Position = 3
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): Position = 4
03-30 10:27:29.453: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): Position = 5
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): Position = 6
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): Position = 7
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): Position = 8
03-30 10:27:29.463: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 0
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NULL
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 1
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 2
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 3
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 4
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 5
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 6
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 7
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): Position = 8
03-30 10:27:29.503: D/TYM(29043): convertView is NOT Null
```

Screenshot:

[image]

From what I understood regarding convertView is, for the first time when items are loaded in the ListView, memory is allocated only to those views that are loaded in the screen, and a few extra for buffer. When we start scrolling, the views that go out of the screen gets recycled to the existing views.

So, when the screen loads for the first time, the convertView will be NULL, and so memory is allocated. The convertView won't be Null ONLY when we start to scroll and views are available for recycling. Is this right?

The Logcat above shows the log when I loaded the screen, for the first time.

My questions:

1. Why are there 3 calls for all the views. Just loaded the screen for the first time....
2. Why is convertView NOT NULL in the second position?
3. Why convertView is NULL in the second cycle again?

Comment: treat them as helping hands, dont assume that they have to appear everytime you would want: if convertView is not null then great, if not thats fine too

Answer (score 1):

To better understand what's going, put a debugger breakpoint in `getView()` and examine the call stacktrace to see why the call was made.

Your `ListView` seems to be in a complex layout that requires multiple measure/layout passes. E.g. `LinearLayout` with weights or `RelativeLayout` with dependencies between children.

To measure a `ListView`, the visible children have to measured. This explains one such call to `getView()`, and for a two-pass layout, two. Also, for measurement purposes, the views can be recycled immediately as they don't need to be shown on screen yet.

Moral: Avoid placing adapterviews in multi-pass layouts. Avoid multi-pass layouts as well if possible.